# Parsing through a CSV file to add users

Tags: ubuntu, csv, useradd

I'm having trouble parsing through a CSV file to add users.

I wrote a small script to add a list of 1000 users:

```
export IFS=","

cat users.csv | while read a b c d e f g; do useradd -d -u $a -U $d ; done
```

The CSV file is formatted as:

```
ps2946,male,Phil Harris,Recording,6508 Hollywood Blvd,Nov 16 1950,760 901 3537
mc3225,male,Mel Blanc,Radio,6385 Hollywood Blvd.,Oct 1 1983,626 647 5560
fn1029,male,Franklin Pangborn,Motion pictures,1500 Vine Street,Mar 10 1911,858 497 6108
we9602,undefined,Webb Pierce,Recording,1600 Vine Street,Sep 3 1988,559 595 6063
```

However upon running the script it iterates through the entire file repeating:

```
useradd: invalid home directory '-u'
```

I used export IFS to separate the words by comma and use them as the parameters for the useradd command.

I read the manual and used the value for the home directory, but I feel like my entire script is off.

Can someone please help me in properly formatting a script to add users from a CSV file?

For reference I used this thread as a base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439536/shell-script-to-parse-through-a-file-csv-and-process-line-by-line

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you're calling `useradd` with the `-d` option , which expects the next word to be the home directory path or directory name in the default home directory (not `-u`).

As a first suggestion, try:

```
cat users.csv | while read a b c d e f g; do useradd -d "$a" -U "$d" ; done
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to add in the other parameters to the stored user? Or would it be better to store the info (phone number, address, birthday) into a comment?

Comment: A comment sounds a good idea, either that or finger information using `chfn`